# Stormpath and internet

Tags: spring-boot, user-management, stormpath

For stormpath to work, is the internet a must? 
I want to implement user management on my springboot server hosted for LAN, where the internet might not be available at times. 
If this is not possible, what are the other options possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my use case, where I was avoiding cloud based user authentication, I used Spring MVC with JPA, Spring Security with user details stored in my local mysql database.

Following link is one of the best tutorial I could find on the same topic.
https://medium.com/@gustavo.ponce.ch/spring-boot-spring-mvc-spring-security-mysql-a5d8545d837d#.gwxd1jdkj

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a connection is required, as user info is stored by Stormpath.  If your connection is intermittent, enabling caching could help.